# To filter rows from a list in a series in a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, series

[image]

The above is a pandas dataframe.
The values in col1 are sort of keys for values in col2
eg: In row 3, "-4" in col1 corresponds to list[12,23] in col2, similarly
    In row 3, "-2" in col1 corresponds to list[12] in col2.

I'm looking to filter out only +ve values in col1 and their corresponding values in col2.

I've tried multiple combinations of `dict(zip(col1,col2))` to filter, but didn't work..

It would be really helpful, if someone can help me on this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how-to](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
Then share the code for your dataframe via `df.to_dict()` so we can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option just using a couple loops

```
row2=[]
col2=[]
row1=[]
col1=[]
for i in range(0,len(df.Col1)):
    for j in range(0,len(df.Col1.tolist()[i])):
        if df.Col1.tolist()[i][j] > 0:
            print i
            print j
            row2.append(df.Col2.tolist()[i][j])
            row1.append(df.Col1.tolist()[i][j])
    col1.append(row1)
    col2.append(row2)
    row1=[]
    row2=[]

df['Col1']=col1
df['Col2']=col2

print(df)

   Member      Col1                   Col2
0      1  [1, 2, 3]  [[12, 23], [12], [4345]]
1      2        [2]                    [[12]]
2      3     [2, 3]         [[4345], [34354]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and a generator comprehension with `enumerate`.

```
import pandas as pd
from operator import itemgetter

df = pd.DataFrame({'Member': [1, 2, 3],
                   'Col1': [[1, 2, 3], [-1, 2], [-4, -2, 2, 3]],
                   'Col2': [[[12, 23], [12], [4345]],
                            [[12, 23], [12]],
                            [[12, 23], [12], [4345], [34354]]]})

def list_filter(row):
    i = ((i, j) for i, j in enumerate(row['Col1']) if j > 0)
    idx, vals = zip(*i)
    return list(vals), list(itemgetter(*idx)(row['Col2']))

df[['Col1', 'Col2']] = df.apply(list_filter, axis=1).values.tolist()

print(df)

        Col1                      Col2  Member
0  [1, 2, 3]  [[12, 23], [12], [4345]]       1
1        [2]                      [12]       2
2     [2, 3]         [[4345], [34354]]       3
```